# Database update fails when file was uploaded

Tags: php, file, upload, idiorm

I have a script where user can attach file to the record. File is stored separately (not in a database). When user does not attach file and click on "Save record" it works fine. When user attaches file it does next steps:

1. File uploads correct
2. Script takes from DB record details using Idiorm
3. Script updates field "filesize" on the record (I tested script without this step - same result)
4. Script tries to save record, and I get this:

   ```
   PDOException

   Code: HY000

   Message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

   File: /home/../includes/idiorm.php

   Line: 1675
   ```

How can it be solved?

**Update:**

I found out 2 things:

1. script returns "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away" only when uploaded file is bigger than 20 Mb and I try to update database with Idiorm_record->save().
2. script does not return "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away" when uploaded file is bigger than 20 Mb and I do not try to update database.
3. I can upload file bigger than 20 Mb and run query generated by Idiorm_record->save() with Idiorm::raw_exec() and catch no error.

Does it mean that problem connected with Idiorm?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the "wait timeout" setting in MySQL. But still is interesting why plain sql works fine and update via save method on Idiorm object causes delay that Mysql goes away.